# InvalidClassException Incompatible class (SUID)

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I am working on an Android application in which one I have to persist some data. In order to persist them, I use the java serialization mechanism.

Here the structure of the class I am serializing :

```
public final class A
    implements Serializable
{

  public static final class B
      implements Serializable
  {

    public final String field1;

    public final String field2;

    public B(String field1, String field2)
    {
      this.field1= field1;
      this.field2= field2;
    }
  }

  public static final class C
      implements Serializable
  {

    public long field1;

    public final B field2;

    public C(B field2)
    {
      this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public void setField1(long field1)
    {
      this.field1= field1;
    }

  }

  private final List<C> list1= new ArrayList<>();

  private final List<C> list2= new ArrayList<>();

  public A()
  {

  }

  public List<C> getList1()
  {
    return list1;
  }

  public List<C> getList2()
  {
    return list2;
  }

  //some other methods

}
```

As you can see, classes implement `Serializable` but I do not specify the `serialVersionUID` static field.

I have to make a big update into this app and remove some methods from the class `A` and `C`.

As expected, when I try to deserialize the old classes into the new ones, I have the following exception :

> Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.A;
>   Incompatible class (SUID): com.my.package.A: static final long
>   serialVersionUID =9103658319690261655L; but expected com.my.package.A:
>   static final long serialVersionUID =7863476896806312319L;
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2336)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1643)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)

So, into my class `A`, I tried to specify the `serialVersionUID` static field with the expected value :

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7863476896806312319L;
```

But my app still crashes... I now have the following stacktrace :

> Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.my.package.A;
>   Incompatible class (SUID): com.my.package.A: static final long
>   serialVersionUID =7863476896806312319L; but expected com.my.package.A:
>   static final long serialVersionUID =9103658319690261655L;
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2336)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1643)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
>                                                                      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)

As you can see, the old `serialVersionUID` field has now the value of the expected one and the expected one has the value of the old `serialVersionUID` field...

So the question is : how can I recover my data and force the deserialization of the old classes into the new ones ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a closely related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920352/java-io-invalidclassexception-during-serializing-deserializing), I think you should try setting the `serialVersionUID` to the expected value of `9103658319690261655L`.

Please try setting:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9103658319690261655L;
```

I hope this helps, give it a try and let us know.

Comment: I was sure that I tried... It works ! Thank you !

Comment: Great! I am glad this helped.